# Supervisor Process Dying on SSH Exit

Tags: linux, ssh, supervisord

I'm attempting to set up Supervisord on a RHEL server where I do not have root access. When I SSH into the server and run supervisord, everything seems to work properly: supervisord and the two programs it starts do not appear when I run ps, but do appear when I run ps -A. I can see the output of the programs, supervisorctl reports that they're running, etc. However, once I exit from the SSH session, supervisord and the two client programs are killed off, no longer show up under ps -A, etc. There's no event in the supervisord log file from when I exit the SSH session and I'm running supervisord with nodaemon=false in the configuration file (see below). Is there something I'm doing wrong or have setup incorrectly in the configuration file? Let me know if additional details are needed.

Command I use to launch supervisord:

```
/home/foo/.local/bin/supervisord
```

Output of `ps -f`:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
foo       1     0  0 09:11 ?        00:00:00 -jailshell
foo      53     1  0 09:11 ?        00:00:00 ps -f

[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock   ; the path to the socket file

[supervisord]
logfile=/home/foo/logs/supervisord.log ; main log file; default 
$CWD/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes=50MB        ; max main logfile bytes b4 rotation; default 50MB
logfile_backups=10           ; # of main logfile backups; 0 means none, default 10
loglevel=trace                ; log level; default info; others: debug,warn,trace
pidfile=/home/foo/.local/supervisord.pid ; supervisord pidfile; default supervisord.pid
nodaemon=false               ; start in foreground if true; default false
minfds=50                    ; min. avail startup file descriptors; default 1024
minprocs=25                   ; min. avail process descriptors;default 200
directory=/home/foo/foo_bar/              ; default is not to cd during start

; The rpcinterface:supervisor section must remain in the config file for
; RPC (supervisorctl/web interface) to work.  Additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate [rpcinterface:x] sections.

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

; The supervisorctl section configures how supervisorctl will connect to
; supervisord.  configure it match the settings in either the unix_http_server
; or inet_http_server section.

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

; The sample program section below shows all possible program subsection values.
; Create one or more 'real' program: sections to be able to control them under
; supervisor.

[program:foo]
command=/home/foo/foo_bar/foo.py              ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)

[program:bar]
command=/home/foo/foo_bar/bar.py              ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
```

Comment: You're logging into this system interactively (through ssh) and launching supervisord from the command line? What specific command do you run to launch supervisord? Could you [edit] your question to show the `ps -f` output of the supervisord process?

Comment: @Kenster, I added the launch command and output of ps -f as requested to my question. I am logging into this system interactively through SSH and launching from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `byobu` if on Debian like system (Ubuntu). It keeps your session fully alive even when you close your `SSH` connection.

Comment: Please don't abuse `\`code\`` for formatting.